SolidJS createEffect only on change after initial
I recently was looking for a way to only react to a change after the first time my component was rendered.
As example:
function NameInput() {
  const [name, setName] = createSignal("");
  const [nameError, setNameError] = createSignal<string | null>(null);

  createEffect(() => {
    setNameError(name().length > 0 ? null : "Name is required");
  })

  return <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={name()} onInput={(e) => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} />
    <Show when={nameError()}>
      <div>{nameError()}</div>  
    </Show>
  </div>
}

However, this would immediately set the error.
The question now is how to only run the createEffect after the initial render on change.
I could not find this anywhere. I will post my solution as an answer here for anyone who stumbles across the same scenario.

So the tricked that worked for me was the on function combined with defer: true:
function NameInput() {
  const [name, setName] = createSignal("");
  const [nameError, setNameError] = createSignal<string | null>(null);

  createEffect(on(name, (name) => {
    setNameError(name.length > 0 ? null : "Name is required");
  }, { defer: true }));

  return <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={name()} onInput={(e) => setName(e.currentTarget.value)} />
    <Show when={nameError()}>
      <div>{nameError()}</div>
    </Show>
  </div>
}


Solid offers multiple solutions, tailoring different use cases. I will go over them one by one. The last one is the solution to this specific problem.
If you need to react to a signal change just once, it is best to use a reaction:
const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
const track = createReaction(() => console.log('Running reaction'));
track(() => count());

The callback will run once when the counter signal is updated. If you want to track the signal again, you need to call the track function again:
track(() => count());

If you need to continuously react to signal updates, use the on method with defer set to true:
const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);

createEffect(on(count, () => {
  // Executes in response to signal updates. 
}, { defer: true }));

If you want to react to changes when component loads, it is best to use onMount as it will run once when component loads.
onMount(() => console.log('Component Mounted'));

Since you are looking for a way to verify a prop value is provided, and display an error when it is missing, it is best to use conditional rendering:
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, Show } from "solid-js";

function User() {
  const [name, setName] = createSignal("");

  const handleChange = (event)=> {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <Show fallback={<div>Name: {name()}</div>} when={!name()}>
      <input value={name()} onChange={handleChange} />
    </Show>
  );
}

render(() => <User />, document.body);

Please note that the state will be updated when the input loses focus.
Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/89fbd7cd-07aa-4d48-889b-c08e7d7ab769
An effect is not a good way to show an error for prop validation because it will be executed after UI is rendered, causing an unnecessary re-render.
PS: I thought you were trying to validate a prop value, but now I see you are trying to collect information from users.
It is better to show error when there is error, instead of when the name is empty. This way you can have more robust feedback mechanism, displaying different errors. For example, if name is not a proper name, you can ask the user provide a proper name.
As you see, you don't need an effect and this is better than having an effect because we avoid unnecessary re-renders.
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, Show, batch } from "solid-js";

function User() {
  const [name, setName] = createSignal("");
  const [error, setError] = createSignal("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    batch(() => {
      if (!value) {
        setName(event.target.value);
        setError("Name can not be empty");
      } else {
        setName(event.target.value);
        setError("");
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name()} onChange={handleChange} />
      <Show when={error()}><label>{error()}</label></Show>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <User />, document.body);

We batch state updates because we are updating two signals at the same time, which will trigger UI update twice if not batched. It is not a problem for this simple example but in an actual application, an extra rendering will cause issues like re-fetching values from remote resources if you have a resource in one of the downstream components.
Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/a2ec38e9-d27a-44c2-8fa2-cb44df3e237d
However, a better alternative would be using an object or a store for tracking multiple values at once.
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, Show } from "solid-js";

function User() {
    const [state, setState] = createSignal({
    name: "",
    nameError: "",
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
      if (!value) {
        setState({
          name: value,
          nameError: "name can not be empty",
        });
      } else {
        setState({
          name: value,
          nameError: ""
        });
      } 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={state().name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <Show when={state().nameError}><label>*{state().nameError}</label></Show>
    </div>
  );
}

render(() => <User />, document.body);

Live Demo: https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/ae44b935-b79a-4300-88a5-dca618db55d7
As a side note, basically there are two ways to collect information and providing feedback to the user:

Controlled Inputs: State is updated immediately upon user action, for instance pressing a key.
Regular Inputs: The state change is executed when user done typing and the input loses focus.

React uses controlled input but it overwrites the default form input behavior. Solid on the other hand remains loyal to the native behavior.
In Solid, onInput will fire immediately after a keypress. onChange will fire when the form field loses focus.
You can read more about it: https://github.com/solidjs/solid/discussions/416

Well your live demo / code does not what I intended or what my provided example does. I still need to render the input field and additionally an error div if the name was changed but is empty...like my example does.
Therefore also your first and third solution are not applicable to the described scenario...and the second one is exactly my solution, which was Downvoted as "not useful" for whatever reason. It works and does exactly what I intedended.
Still I want to compliment you for your effort...It is just that the most part of your answer is not the solution to the described problem.

As I elaborated in my answer, an effect is not a proper way to show error as it will trigger unnecessary re-render. Any effected downstream component will be re-mounted.
